# PostgreSQL UNIQUE constraint and REFERENCES

Tags: sql, postgresql, unique-constraint

Let's say I have a table tree and a table special_tree

```
CREATE TABLE tree VALUES (name VARCHAR(32) UNIQUE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                          type VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE special_tree VALUES (name NOT NULL REFERENCES tree(name),
                                  treat_date DATE,
                                  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
```

So I have a table containing a list of trees with unique names BUT I want to say that a tree can have multiple 'treat_date' (for various reasons).
Since tree(name) is unique I can't add 2 same name in special_tree.

Is the only solution is to remove unique from tree and then add everywhere i handle the tree table an IF statement to check if name isn't already there? `(IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM tree where tree.name = ...))`

Comment: the 'name' of 'tree' should'n be use as row id, add new field to 'tree' named for id, example:  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment and set it as primarykey,

Comment: Sure, but its just an example, it doesn't help me with the unique name situation. Ok i get it, you want me to reference the id.

Comment: there is no reason to set on name unique constrain

Comment: It's for some work where I'm forced to set a row name as unique. If it was up to me I'd indeed do something differently.

Comment: you can add new table, eg. 'tree_names' only for with name field, and use it as reference for both existing tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you consider the column `name` of the table `tree` it doesn't mean that all referenced columns also should have unique values. Take a look at [this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6580d)

Comment: Nop... You example doesn't work.

https://i.gyazo.com/bf85955fba9bc8c7530f6f90c3af7d82.png

Which is exactly my problem.

Comment: It works as is? Why are you trying to insert the values once more? However, you can notice that your try violate primary key constraint, not unique one.

Comment: To verify the example simply build the scheme and execute any select query.

Answer (score 0):

the best solution for this is (for MySQL):

```
CREATE TABLE tree VALUES (
  id_t int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  type VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT tree_pk PRIMARY KEY (id_t));

CREATE TABLE special_tree VALUES (
  id_st int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  id_t NOT NULL REFERENCES tree(id_t),
  treat_date DATE,
  CONSTRAINT special_tree_pk PRIMARY KEY (id_st));
```

for PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE tree VALUES (
  id_t serial primary key,
  name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  type VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE special_tree VALUES (
  id_st serial primary key,
  id_t NOT NULL REFERENCES tree(id_t),
  treat_date DATE);
```